# Youtube iframe is not working on google interactive canvas when loaded on google hub

Tags: javascript, reactjs, iframe, youtube, actions-on-google

How to successfully embed youtube videos on google interactive canvas when played on google hub?

**Background:**
I'm working on a project to use google actions to be used on google nest hub. I've set up a canvas with a website URL that was built using ReactJS. I've a scene to display an embedded youtube videos on my website which will be displayed on google nest hub.

**Problem:**
The embedded youtube videos doesn't load/work when I test it on google nest hub (alpha test version deployment) but it works when I test it on my actions console (refer to image #1) and my Samsung device. What I would define as working is the youtube video was able to be loaded and user can interact with it using the button on the player. I get blank iframe on google nest hub although source has been loaded on iframe (refer to image #2).

#1 [Youtube videos on actions console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tpLBp.png)

#2 [Youtube videos on google nest hub](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e4VSe.jpg)

On this screen, I've set up 5 way of embedding a youtube video on a ReactJS apps:

1. Using [react-player](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-player)
2. Using our built-in player using [Youtube iframe API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference)
3. Using [iframe tag](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_youtube.asp)
4. Using object tag
5. Using video tag with local mp4 file

**Sample Code**:
You can refer to following JSfiddle: [YoutubeTestCode](https://jsfiddle.net/marcosumali/5x8j3u96/)
For the sample code, I would just provide the code for iframe tag and object tag because I believe the rest is similar with these methods.

```
const VideoApp = () => { 
  return (
    <div className="container">
      <div className="grid">
        <div className="card">
          <div>3. Iframe Tag</div>
          <div>Source: https://www.youtube.com/embed/tgbNymZ7vqY</div>
          <iframe 
            id="blank-iframe"
            width="95%" 
            height="140px"
            src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/tgbNymZ7vqY">
          </iframe>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="grid">
        <div className="card">
          <div>4. Object Tag</div>
          <div>Source: https://www.youtube.com/embed/tgbNymZ7vqY</div>
          <object 
            id="object-method"
            data="https://www.youtube.com/embed/tgbNymZ7vqY" 
            width="95%" 
            height="140px"
          >
          </object>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

If you need more info, pls let me know.
Thanks !!!